# Set select options with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

How do I set an `option` value in `select` list with jQuery? I tried:

```
$('#SelectGroup :all').replace("tmp4", "abc");
```

I mean: Search for *tmp4* string and replace it with *abc*. In the list, there are 4 items I don't mind going directly to entrance #4.

I will extend my question: I want to pass to the function that replaces a value from outside. I tried:

```
$('#SelectGroup option').each(function(fieldNum, newVal) { 
      this.text = this.text.replace('tmp4',$(newVal).text());
    });
});
```

and I tried:

```
$('#SelectGroup option').each(newVal, function() { 
      this.text = this.text.replace('tmp4',newVal);
    });
});
```

but here it says it fails! in the first line of `.each`

Why?

I don't understand! I pass a value to a function but it loses its value in the function and change

```
var newVal=  $(this).val();
$('#SelectGroup option').each(function(fieldNum, newVal) { 
    alert("final option text is:" + $(this).text());*/
    alert($(newVal).text());
    this.text = this.text.replace('tmp4',$(newVal).text());  
    });
});
```

but newVal is not what I pass to the function - it is what the for each gives it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesen't $('option value=["' + value + '"]') work?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to replace in the text or value of the options?

```
var replacement = 'abc';

$('#SelectGroup option').each(function() { 
    this.text = this.text.replace('tmp4', replacement );
    this.value = this.value.replace('tmp4', replacement );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be more efficient to include only the options which contain your search string, to reduce the number of iterations (thus reducing the number of `replace` calls):

```
$('#SelectGroup option[value*=tmp4]').each(function() { 
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace('tmp4', 'abc'));
});
```

See the [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector.

Answer (score 0):

solve it another way:

```
$("input[name*=RELATIVE_symbol]").live("focusout", function(){
      var fieldNum =  $(this).attr('id').replace("RELATIVE_symbol_","");

      var newVal=  $(this).val();

      var a = $("#SelectGroup option[value='"+fieldNum+"']").attr('text').replace('tmp'+ fieldNum,newVal);
      $("#SelectGroup option[value='"+fieldNum+"']").text(a);

    });
```